# Show the files that are not covered by tests

Tags: bun

When running tests with coverage `bun test --coverage` I get a nice report for all the files that were included by the tests.

BUT the files that aren't included by any tests have no coverage and I would like to know if there are any of those about.

Is it possible to configure bun so that it will show files in the project that aren't included in the tests?

Answer (score 0):

Currently bun doesn't have that feature.
We can track this issue for more info https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/5928